# как на php добавлять id блоку по возрастанию id="n1" id="n2" id="n3"

Tags: php

```html
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>

            <div class="n">
              <label class="control-label" for="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
              <?php echo $text_select; ?>
                <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                <span><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                <?php } ?>
                </span>
                <?php } ?>
              
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

блоки генерируются через php `<div id="n"></div>` блоков на страницы может быть около 10 как мне прописать что бы у каждого блока был уникальный id по типа id="n1"  id="n2" id="n3"

Comment: если бы я знал как это делать

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```html
<?php

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
echo "<div id='$i'></div>";
}
```

Если речь идет о переборе массива в цикле, создайте переменную счетчик перед началом цикла, и увеличивайте ее перед окончанием прохода цикла, или в его начале.

Comment: не могли бы подсказать как внедрить его в мой код, давил в вопросе код

Comment: Это цикл? Перебор массива? 
В коде я вижу только проверку значения, ожидаемо что этот код работает в цикле, в каком?

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев, если делать просто, то добавить перед foreach переменную равну первому элементу, т.е. 1, а дальше просто в цикле её увеличивать.

Comment: извините я не сильно понимаю в php но на сайт выводит блоки этот код и он один в файле а на странице много блоков

Comment: Если кода цикла вы не видите в файле, вероятно его нужно искать в другом месте. Чаще всего это будет цикл foreach который переберет массив, если это так решением будет создание переменной счетчика. Как это сделать я написал вам чуть выше. 
"создайте переменную счетчик перед началом цикла, и увеличивайте ее перед окончанием прохода цикла, или в его начале"

Comment: Так же в коде у вас есть 
$option['product_option_id'] - Если этот айдишник уникален, а судя по всему так и есть, можете использовать его вместо счетчика, это будет более элегантным решением. 
<div class="<?php echo $option['product_option_id'];  ?>">
Но тогда вероятно результат будет не по возрастанию, а просто уникальным, этого как правило достаточно, если вас интересует исключительно возрастающий результат без счетчика вам не обойтись